# SumTotal in the end of each group classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

What i am trying to do is get the Sum Total in the last line. Here an example with 2 groups of itens with the sum:

I have:

```
1000 (group number)

TitleUm   TitleTres   TitleQuatro
Apple     1           20
Pear      5           12

1001 (group number)

TV        1           20
Mobile    1           12
Car       1           15
Bicycle   1            5

 TOTAL   10           84
```

---

I am looking for:

```
1000 (group number)

TitleUm   TitleTres   TitleQuatro
Apple     1           20
Pear      5           12

 TOTAL    6           32
```

---

```
1001 (group number)

TV        1           20
Mobile    1           12
Car       1           15
Bicycle   1            5

 TOTAL    4           52
```

---

The code bellow do almost everything, listing the item and each value per line, but it does now show the sum total:

```
<table class="Itens">
<%
currentGroupName = ""
previousGroupName = ""
Do Until ItensList.EOF
currentGroupName = ItensList("oito")
Um= ItensList("um")
Tres= ItensList("tres")
Quatro= CCur(ItensList("quatro"))

If currentGroupName <> previousGroupName Then
%>

<tr>
<td><% Response.Write currentGroupName %></td>
</tr>
<tr>            
<th><% Response.Write TituloUm %></th>
<th><% Response.Write TituloTres %></th>
<th><% Response.Write TituloQuatro %></th>
</tr>

<%
End If
%>

<%
Um= CCur(ItensList("um"))
Tres= CCur(ItensList("tres"))
Quatro= CCur(ItensList("quatro"))
%>

<tr>
<td><% Response.Write Um %></td>
<td><% Response.Write Tres %></td>
<td><% Response.Write Quatro %></td>
</tr>

<%
previousGroupName = currentGroupName
ItensList.MoveNext
Loop
ItensList.Close
%>

<tr class="Total">
<td>TOTAL</td>
<td><% Response.Write ShowSumTotalTresHere %></td>
<td><% Response.Write ShowSumTotalQuatroHere %></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Add each to a variable inside the loop like this:

```
<%
SumSomething = 0

Do Until objRs.EoF
     SumSomething = SumSomething + objRs("SomeValue")
objRs.MoveNext
Loop
%>
...
<tr>
  <td><%= SumSomething%></td>
...
```

Comment: Thanks, but the original code add the total line only in the end of the group list instead of add the total line on each group (1000...1001...)

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain a running total whilst your looping, take my example code below, i declare two new vars before the loop:

```
Total_Tres          = 0
Total_Quatro        = 0
```

I then incremement these in your loop:

```
'Maintain Running Total
Total_Tres          = Total_Tres + Tres
Total_Quatro        = Total_Quatro + Quatro
```

And finally, output the total vars:

```
<td>TOTAL</td>
<td><% = Total_Tres %></td>
<td><% = Total_Quatro %></td>
```

**Full Example (untested)**

```
<table class="Itens">
<%
currentGroupName    = ""
previousGroupName   = ""
Total_Tres          = 0
Total_Quatro        = 0
Do Until ItensList.EOF
    currentGroupName    = ItensList("oito")
    Um                  = ItensList("um")
    Tres                = ItensList("tres")
    Quatro              = CCur(ItensList("quatro"))

    If currentGroupName <> previousGroupName Then
        %>
        <tr>
            <td><% = currentGroupName %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>            
            <th><% = TituloUm %></th>
            <th><% = TituloTres %></th>
            <th><% = TituloQuatro %></th>
        </tr>
        <%
    End If

    Um      = CCur(ItensList("um"))
    Tres    = CCur(ItensList("tres"))
    Quatro  = CCur(ItensList("quatro"))
    %>
    <tr>
        <td><% = Um %></td>
        <td><% = Tres %></td>
        <td><% = Quatro %></td>
    </tr>
    <%
    '#### Maintain Running Total
    Total_Tres          = Total_Tres + Tres
    Total_Quatro        = Total_Quatro + Quatro

    '### Flag current group
    previousGroupName   = currentGroupName
    ItensList.MoveNext
Loop
ItensList.Close
%>
<tr class="Total">
<td>TOTAL</td>
<td><% = Total_Tres %></td>
<td><% = Total_Quatro %></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will keep the total line only in the last of the groups, instead of one total line per group.

Comment: @Khrys I was just showing the concept, all you need to do is print the totals when the group changes then reset the running totals to 0 - let me know if you still don’t understand and I’ll edit my answer.

Comment: I try do what you said, but without success... can you please show me? thanks a lot

Comment: HeavenCore, just to clarify... i am trying to find the last record per group, so I can put the total line there... thansk again

Comment: anyone more can help me with this?